# Add Clipping Mask on Pen Stroke Path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a text object with a **white** pen stroke running through it. I want to make that path a clipping mask, so that it would be a transparency instead of a white line, so that I can put it on any background.

[image]

When I do a Clipping Mask however, this is what I get:
[image]

My pen stroke is the top-most layer as well.

Assistance plz.

Comment: Why don't you make two clipping masks and make them fit together separated by the whitespace, then group them?

You could also consider using pathfinder for this.

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that. This is like my second time ever using Illustrator.

Comment: @andross Ok so I finally got that to work, however one problem: when I separate the top and bottom, the letters look all weird and elongated because that's not the letter's natural position after the stroke.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to expand the stroke so it is a closed path: Object>expand

Next fill the new shape black place it where you want it. Copy it and delete it.

Now select the text object and create a new opacity mask. Paste your clipping shape in the opacity mask. uncheck clip.

[image]

Comment: I'm obviously doing this wrong, but now I just have a black line on top of my text. And I made sure the Opacity Mask had the same settings as yours.

Comment: Hey, sorry.. you didn't need to click invert.. I have updated answer and added a gif to show the process better